# Customize mydatepicker in angular 2 format dd:mm:yy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have tried the date picker in angular 2. https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker#options-attribute

```
import {IMyDpOptions} from 'mydatepicker';
// other imports here...

export class MyTestApp {

    private myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
        // other options...
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    };

    // Initialized to specific date (09.10.2018).
    private model: Object = { date: { year: 2018, month: 10, day: 9 } };

    constructor() { }
}
```

There is no option to customize year in **yy** format. can anybody suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible with that library. Either fork it and make changes yourself or try another one (for example PrimeNG calendar) that supports two-digit years. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: Have you tried YY?